# XNA equivalency of unity function Transform.InverseTransformDirection

Tags: c#, xna, rotation, unity-game-engine, quaternions

Looking for the C# XNA equivalent of this function this question is in relation to the below post (Currently Unanswered),

[world velocity to local (ship might be flying backward so need worlds negative velocity etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387050/world-velocity-to-local-ship-might-be-flying-backward-so-need-worlds-negative-v/17387790?noredirect=1#comment25242189_17387790)

This problem which i am also having is easily solved in unity by the above function, if anyone could supply the mathematical code behind this function or write a small function which achieves the same result, that person would be !!! AWESOME !!! As we have been trying to fix this problem for days.

For a detailed explanation of the problem see the post of my friend listed above.

Thank you all in advance <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the inverse of a matrix in XNA and then use it by doing this:

```
Matrix inverseMatrix = Matrix.Inverse(myMatrix);
Vector3 result = Vector3.Transform(myVector, inverseMatrix);
```

From my understanding, though, you want to ignore the translation when getting the inverse. So you've got a direction only (basically this accounts for rotation, scale, etc). I've not tested this myself, but I *think* this should do what you want:

```
Matrix copyOfMyMatrix = myMatrix;
copyOfMyMatrix.Translation = Vector3.Zero; // reset the translation components
Matrix inverseMatrix = Matrix.Inverse(copyOfMyMatrix);
Vector3 result = Vector3.Transform(myVector, inverseMatrix);
```